# Start function when users stops typing from different component

Tags: angular

I currently have it setup where a user can type in the search bar in the header component and whatever they type gets assigned to this.message using a service I created. I can set a delay in the component I type in and then kick off a function, but I can't figure out how to start the function in main component when the `this.message` value changes?

Header component

```
    <form class="example-form">
      <mat-form-field class="searchField" [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px': 12}" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label id="placeholder">Find User</mat-label>
        <input type="text" name="username" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
          (input)="onInput($event)" name='username' [(ngModel)]="username">

      </mat-form-field>
    </form>



  onInput(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;

    this.searchService.changeMessage(value);
  }
```

Main component

```
   this.searchService.currentMessage
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe(message => {
        this.message = message;
        console.log("THIS MESSAGE");
        console.log(this.message);
      });
```

search service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class SearchService {
  searchIsActive: boolean;
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}
  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }

}
```

Comment: An event emitter, service, or simply calling the other method on keypress ses sufficiently.have you tried any of that?

Comment: I want to call the function from the main component. The search service is already passing the value and I can see it appear as I type using  ```{{this.message}}``` in main component. I'm not really sure how to get the function to start from the main component though. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Which function do you want to invoke from the main component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a function in Main component to be triggered everytime the this.message value changes. You can do that by just calling your function from inside your subscribe block, something like this:

```
export class MainComponent {

  // Some code

  this.searchService.currentMessage
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
    .subscribe(message => {
      this.message = message;
      console.log("THIS MESSAGE");
      console.log(this.message);
      this.myFunction(); <-- CALLING IT HERE
    });

  myFunctions() {
    // Does something
  }

}
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was that easy. Thanks for pointing that out!